# How to execute a function when opening a modal (Angular 4)?

Tags: angular

My problem is that I'm loading a function from a service associated with an id. This execution function in the onInit, but the modal component load inside my main component the function always loads empty and not when I open the modal

Template home, from here charge my modal:

```
<app-modal modalId="editUser" modalSize="modal-lg" modalTitle="Editar Usuario - {{user.userId}}" modalIcon="ion-ios-person-outline">
  <app-edit-user [user]="user"></app-edit-user>
</app-modal>
```

Component home

```
onRowSelect(event) {
   this.newUser = false;
   this.user = this.cloneUser(event.data);
   $("#editUser").modal();
}
```

Modal template

```
getParameters(user){
    console.log(user);
    this._userService.getParameter(user).subscribe(
      response => {
      this.userParameter = response.pagedResult.resultado;
      console.log(this.userParameter);
    }, 
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }
```

OnInit component modal, Always comes empty

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.user.userId);
    this.getParameters(this.user.userId);
  }
```

Comment: you should use `resolve` before the modal opens

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve: it seems that your code uses `this.user` to populate the modal, and `this.getParameters(...)` populates `this.userParameters`, but you make no use of it

Comment: My problem is that when I load the modal, my function getParameters loads empty.

Comment: My intention is to load the function when the module is opened and not when loading the component